# Performance improvement for calculating the powerset of a list of integers

Tags: python, math

I am trying to compute the powerset of a list of prime numbers. I have already done some research and the prefered way of doing this seems to be using a line like
`itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(primes, r) for r in range(2, len(primes) + 1))`
and then iterating over all combinations to get the products with `math.prod()`. All in all, the code currently looks like this:

```
number = 200
p1 = []
# calculate all primes below specified number 
for i in range(2, number + 1):
    isPrime = True
    for prime in p1:
        if i % prime == 0:
            isPrime = False
    if isPrime:
        p1.append(i)

Pp = []
myIterable = itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(p1, r) for r in range(2, len(p1) + 1))
# convert iterable to integer array of products -- The code below is extremely slow and should be improved
for x in myIterable:
    newValue = math.prod(x)
    if newValue <= number:
        Pp.append(newValue)
```

This works, but it is not feasible for any "number" greater than 100 because of too high execution time. The problem is the last for loop, which takes forever to compute. Everything else performs reasonably well. The powerset has to be constricted to sets, whos products are less or equal to number, as done using the last if statement, or else the memory will explode.

Comment: A power set has `2**n` elements. You have 46 primes under 200. That means you are hoping to iterate through `70368744177664` combinations. That doesn't seem especially feasible to me.

Comment: Yeah, thats the problem. I guess, there is no easy way and I just have to do some more data filtering beforehand.

Comment: If I have understood correctly you are taking the powerset of a list of prime numbers, hence are unique and their product as well. Instead of the list `Pp` you can use a `set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to create a pointer array, which crawls through the prime array until the product of the pointed primes gets too high. The needed helper functions can be implemented like this:

```
def calcProductOfPointers(pointerArray, dataArray):
    prod = 1
    for pointer in pointerArray:
        prod *= dataArray[pointer]
    return prod


def incrementPointer(pointerArray, dataArray, threshold):
    ret = False
    for i in range(1, len(pointerArray) + 1):
        index = len(pointerArray) - i
        pointerArray[index] += 1
        if calcProductOfPointers(pointerArray, dataArray) <= threshold and pointerArray[index] < len(dataArray):
            ret = True
            break
        elif index > 0:
            pointerArray[index] = pointerArray[index - 1] + 2
        else:
            break
    return ret
```

And then the iteration over all powersets can be substituted with this code:

```
Pp = []
for i in range(2, len(p1) + 1):     # start at a minimum of 2 prime factors
    primePointers = []
    for index in range(i):
        primePointers.append(index)
    if calcProductOfPointers(primePointers, p1) > number:
        break
    while calcProductOfPointers(primePointers, p1) <= number:
        Pp.append(calcProductOfPointers(primePointers, p1))
        if not incrementPointer(primePointers, p1, number):
            break
```